# Mac OSX 10.7.4, Xcode 4.4.1, no <array> header file?

Tags: xcode, arrays, include, g++

I am writing a program that will use the array container of the C++ Standard Library to hold some objects. However, whenever I try to include the following line of code in my program:

```
#include <array>
```

I receive the following error at compile time:

```
75-143-76-177:soft jeffersonhudson$ g++ mms.cpp -o mms
mms.cpp:5:17: error: array: No such file or directory 
75-143-76-177:soft jeffersonhudson$
```

Commenting out the #include lets me compile just fine. Surely I am overlooking something simple? I have installed the "Command Line Tools" in Xcode, am I still missing something?

EDIT:

I have found the location of array on my computer

```
/usr/clang-ide/lib/c++/v1
```

knowing that, what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<array>` is provided in C++11, you need to provide the `-std=c++11` flag to enable it, and provide the `-stdlib=libc++` flag for the corresponding library. But the g++ provided by Xcode is so old which doesn't have much support for C++11. Could you switch to clang?

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ mms.cpp -o mms
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting my code formatted correctly in this response box. I also get an error when using that command.

Comment: The comment box strips formatting. This is my error when I use clang++ -std=c++11 mms.cpp -o mms http://pastie.org/4761513

Comment: Yes, adding the -stdlib=libc++ flag works. Do you have a link where I can read about what these flags do and how they work? I'll look around for it myself of course, just wondering if you know of one in particular.

Comment: @JeffersonHudson you can check the [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/clang.1.html).

Answer (score 5):

from the looks of it, you are not using LLVM's libc++, but GCC's libstdc++.

to use `std::array` in the latter context, use:

```
#include <tr1/array>
```

if you want to use libc++ and C++11, then alter your compiler flags as KennyTM suggested (+1).

Comment: Thank you very much - if you don't mind my asking, what does changing <array> to <tr1/array> do that causes it to understand where the file is located?

Comment: @JeffersonHudson it's for historical reasons. tr1 is an extension to the library, initially added in 2003 -- this is when `std::array` became a part of the C++ standard library. libc++ is brand new, and it's laid out as a more modern representation of the standard library (C++11). so you have two standard libraries on osx -- libc++ is designed for C++11. the command line options Kenny mentioned will alter the `#include` search paths. GCC's libstdc++ on osx is now a little dated (not a bad thing if you need backwards compatibility) -- it placed `std::array` in a subdirectory `tr1/`.