# Array file not found mac - compiling package via python

Tags: python, c++, xcode

I'm compiling a package called GMES https://sourceforge.net/projects/gmes/

The summary of my issue is to install I do

```
sudo python  setup.py install
```

Then I get

```
src/pw_material.hh:5:10: fatal error: 'array' file not found
#include <array>
```

I tried to find an answer on my own, which I found here

[Mac OSX 10.7.4, Xcode 4.4.1, no <array> header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516830/mac-osx-10-7-4-xcode-4-4-1-no-array-header-file)

but it seems to me that they were using clang instead of what I'm using. I'm not exactly sure how I get my command to find the c++11 stuff. If someone could help me on this issue, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try editing the `setup.py` file and change all instances of `-std=c++0x` to `-std=c++11` (I see two of them).